# Why was this flag I started disputed?

Tags: discussion, specific-flag

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/588247/81560.

The question is "Good Online Resources to learn Multivariate Statistics?"

Multivariate statistics is a very broad field, including many subtopics. The question does *not* ask for an explanation of any one of those subtopics.

The answer I linked above is an explanation of one of those subtopics. It does not mention anything about online resources to learn about multivariate statistics.

I flagged this post as "not an answer" and got the "disputed" status back.

Why is this? The answer does not answer the question.

Comment: Not completely sure, but it should be related to this [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/939199).

Comment: If your question is mainly about this particular situation, you should add ([meta-tag:specific-flag]) tag. But not if this flag is just an example of a more general issue which you wish to discuss. See [the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-flag/info) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag is "disputed" as the *users* (not moderators) reviewing your flag disagreed that it should be deleted. Why exactly they thought so is hard to know.

A reason might be that Not An Answer has a quite particular meaning and it is often said not to use this too widely. Somebody rigid about the definition of NAA might decide the post does not fall under it.

Another reason might be that in the review-queue the answer is more evaluated in isolation. Thus, not answering the question might not be noticed.

Since the verdict of the users was clear, no moderator flag was raised (which is raised in certain cases where the community review is inconclusive).