# Disputed flag for a question posted as an answer

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, specific-flag

A few days ago I flagged [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104980/356647) as `Not An Answer` (NAA) where the user actually says that *"I just observed this numerically and wondered why"*.

That is, the user attempts to answer a 1-year-old post using a mathematical claim that is unproven (to the user).

I flagged it for deletion since I believe it is better make a new question (which is literally what the "answer" post is about) and link to the original post. This seems to me to be the proper course even for the sake of providing new content to the old post.

My flag turned out to be disputed.

A negligence on my part was that back then I didn't leave a comment (as seen now) explaining the reason why I flagged it as NAA.

I understand that the decision making process differ a lot among reviewers, and [NAA is not the easiest for people to agree on](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27741/356647).

Having said that, **I'm wondering**

1. Are there formal other ways for me to "nominate" the post to be considered for deletion essentially for this same rationale? (I cannot flag it again for the same reason)
2. If it just so happens that someone else flags this answer for the same reason (NAA) and the new flag goes through undisputed, would it change my flagging record?

Comment: It seems to me that the answer  by now does contain an argument. I think you might misinterpret the last sentence. As it stands now, I don't see a strong reason to delete it.

Comment: @quid I agree—it's now basically "I noticed this then proved it as above".

Comment: Appreciate your input. Indeed, back when I raised the flag it was the very first version (before any revision), and the following part of the sentence was not there `proof was a bit trickier than on first appearances`, along with other stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the questions asked, independent of the current post:

Regarding the question whether later actions would change your flagging record the answer is "no." Once a flag is cleared its status does not change anymore later on.

Regarding what else to do. If we take "formal" as meaning to involve moderators, then you could flag "in need of moderator intervention" and explain the situation. Other than that, you could bring it to the attention of other users via chat and see what they think. The room [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude) is dedicated to this type of issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment below the question post and this answer. By "formal" I just mean "procedurally" other than e.g. the OP seeing my comment and take recommended action. Indeed, next time (hopefully not gonna happen) I'll go to the chat room first.